# Why am I unable to define weights and why are my settings being reverting on save?

Tags: 7

I am going to cry :(

I have built a number of sites in the last few months that are all starting to fall apart with the same issue.

There are no notices/errors and there is nothing in the dblog.

It appears to be affecting any Drupal form with  with a select list.

It's affecting everything from Core Search Settings, Block weights, Context Weights and Omega theme weights/region widths

I define block weights, press save and all of the weights are set to the same weight e.g. all of my 50 block weights show "-10"

I define the widths of my regions in omega, press save. They are all reverted to '1'

I change core cron settings to index 500 at a time, press save. It reverts back to 100.

The closest I can come to my issue (and I have definitely done my research) is:

http://drupal.org/node/1439134

It references a recent change to core at 
http://drupal.org/node/1346760

However, it seems to be affecting damn near everything, so I am unsure if this is even the source.

If anyone has any suggestion of what might be happening or what I can even do to source the culprit, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are all the websites on the same server ? If yes, are you sure your server meets the [Drupal requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) ? Also, is there anything in the server logs indicating something about the POST and GET resquests ?

Comment: How about the php memory_limit on the server? I had once something similar and to increase the limit fixed this.

Comment: The sites are all on different VPSs with more than adequate resources. The sites were all originally spawned from a single installation. Copied, then customized. The problem is that I cannot source when the issue started to come up, so there is no way to retrace my steps. Normally in Drupal there is some sort of error or something in the dblog that at least helps to point you in a direction. I have absolutely nothing to go on. :(

Comment: As for the server logs. All I see are a ton of '66.249.73.214 - - [24/May/2012:09:48:34 -0700] "GET /taxonomy/term/153/all?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 9897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"' and '50.92.219.74 - - [24/May/2012:06:34:51 -0700] "GET /misc/grippie.png HTTP/1.1" 200 106 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/css/css_CKoWqiBj9gVXhPuDSnNphuEB0b0J2To76x0pX0EGqn4.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"

Comment: @Countzero is there something in the POST and GET requests that I might look for?

Comment: I was just asking myself if something was actually submitted by the forms, so checking the log seemed to be a good idea. Searching for the submitted form's "action" property should do.

Comment: After much tinkering and a bit of help on D.O it turns out this issue was due to a bug in http://drupal.org/project/jump_menu which really makes this question not applicable to stack exchanges format. Thank you Countzero and Lance for chiming in with some ideas.